# Metrics for Cosmos DB on Azure portal are incorrect

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

For a single subscription our Cosmos DB's throughput metrics(Azure portal) are displaying incorrectly...

**The problem:** Navigate to a Cosmos DB on the Azure portal, select 'Metrics'. Under the Throughput tab, three metrics are displaying incorrectly for all collections.

**The top two metrics** ('Request Throughput in RU/s' and 'Number of requests exceeded capacity') broke first, displaying 'No data to display' early last week.

**The third metric** ('Max consumed RU/s per partition key range') started to display incorrectly a couple of days after the first two. This metric seems to work fine when using the '1 hour' time span, however changing to any other time span causes the values to jump by ten times their actual value.

[Here you can see the behavior of metric #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w742t.png)

Any response is appreciated and I can provide more information if needed - thank you,

Connor

Comment: In 3rd chart you are hitting a bug, we are aware of it, and fixing soon. For Top 2 charts can you please check again, it may be an intermittent problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is (apparently) a bug report or intermittent issue; not a programming issue.

Comment: Thank you for the information Rafat. The top two metrics have been showing this behaviour for over a week now, I will check again and open a new question for just those charts if needed. Thanks.

Comment: I have also noticed that the metrics dashboard consistently shows inaccurate information on the RU/s in the last X time period.  I was hitting it with several tasks, each inserting documents into my collection, and it was constantly telling me I had a rate of 20 RU/s regardless of my real activity rate.

Comment: Is this bug resolved now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially a bug report (and now, an announcement of it being fixed). Not a programming issue at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update this old post and mark it as answered. Azure responded, this was a bug with an update and is now fixed.